# Rails 5.1 different sum calculation with multiple currencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sum, ruby-on-rails-5, currency, calculation

I'm working on a Rails app for my expenses.
Basically I enter some expenses giving a name, description, amount, currency and a date.
For this I have 3 models : User, Spending, Currency with this relations :

```
class Currency < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :spendings
    has_many :users, through: :spendings

end

class Spending < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :currency

end

class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :spendings
  has_many :currencies, through: :spendings

end
```

I'm using the show from the users_controller to index each user expenses. This is what I have in my users_controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @user_spendings = @current_user.spendings.all.order('date DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
        @user_amount = @user_spendings.sum(:amount)
    end
end
```

In this scenario the @user_amount shows me all the expenses from the current_user, the thing is that I have 2 currencies (maybe more in the future) and I would like to show different total amount depending on which currency has been selected when I create a new expense.
I thought about different things here, I tried to do a If statement so that the amount shows only if the currency_id == to 1 if € or to 2 if $ etc... But this wont work well if I add new currencies (and I couldn't make it work).
Maybe a loop ? Loop through the currencies and somehow show the total amount. But you can't do a sum in a loop so I don't know.
Also I'd like it to be flexible, so if in the future I add more currencies that I don't have to touch the code.
Any idea ?
If needed here is my show.html.erb

```
  <% @user_spendings.each do |spending| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= spending.title %></td>
    <td><%= spending.description %></td>
    <td><%= '%.02f' % spending.amount %></td>
    <td><%= spending.currency.symb %></td>
    <td><%= spending.date.strftime('%d %B %Y') %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Thanks alot.

Comment: I found something like that :  Spending.where(id: Currency.where(name: 'Euro').select(:spending_id)).sum(:amount) but it shows me 0 as a result :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing something along the lines of:

```
@sums_by_currency = Currency.joins(:spendings).
  select(:symb, 'SUM(spendings.amount) AS amount').
  where(spendings: { id: @user_spendings.map(&:id) }).
  group(:symb)
```

would allow you to iterate over the currencies as in:

```
@sums_by_currency.each do |currency|
  "#{currency.symb}#{currency.amount}"
end
```

or

```
@sums_by_currency.each do |currency|
  number_to_currency(currency.amount, unit: currency.symb)
end
```

in your view.

Comment: Hey there I tried your way as well. Its working but it shows me the total sum in € and $ on one line like that : €.-40.00. Basically it sum all the amounts

Comment: Just making sure you used the updated view code - I updated it not too long ago.

Comment: Are you saying that you have, for example, two expenses, one worth €26 and one worth $14 and the view is just spitting out €40?

Comment: Ah, just noticed that I'd never added the group. Modified the query to add a `group` clause

Comment: Hey there, sorry to bother but I run into a other issue. It's a different problem but it's related to your code that you gave me. Maybe you could take a loop and help me again ? [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48386920/rails-5-1-chartkick-a-sum-with-multiple-currencies/48391383#48391383). Would be really cool, and sorry to bother... :/

Answer (score 0):

If you have already set up relations between your tables, you can actually access all the `Spendings` that belongs_to `Currency` by doing the following

```
Currency.all.each do |c|
  c.spendings.sum(&:amount)
end
```

Or for every single currency you can do it like this:

```
Currency.first.spendings.all
```

*to check all the expenses on the **first*** `Currency`

```
Currency.first.spendings.sum(&:amount)
```

*to check the sum of all the expenses of the **first*** `Currency`

Of course, this can be done for all the other models that have the `has_many - belongs_to` relation

Comment: Hey there and thanks for the answer. The first one works. The second one I got this error on the page : #<Spending::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x6835590> and the third the page doesn't load and show me this : undefined method `spending' for #<Currency:0xb4a2b10>. Do I have a problem with my relations here ? Also the first solution would fit except that I would like to show the sum of the current_user in different currencies. The first option gives me the total amount of all the users. Thanks

Comment: I had a typo in my second code section. Generally, you need to use plural in model relation so have in mind that you'll always need to use `.spendings` and not `spending`. The error `<Spending::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x6835590>` means that you have no `spendings` for `Currency.first`.  Additionally the per-user spending can normally be accessed like `current_user.curruncies.first.spendings.all`. But you first have to define the `current_user`. If you are using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) its predefined by the gem!

Comment: For the second code I still have this issue : #<Spending::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0xa057158>. The current_user is define in a helper but if I try this : <%= @current_user.currencies.first.spendings.all %> I have this error : #<Spending::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0xb1b03d0>. I have 3 expenses in euro and 1 in $ on the first account and 1 expense in € on the second account.

Comment: Those are not errors they are empty hashes! Can you please paste the output of the `Spending.first` after running it on the rails console

Comment: #<Spending id: 20, title: "CNTFS", description: "Way to much...", amount: #<BigDecimal:65b69b0,'0.335E3',9(18)>, user_id: 1, created_at: "2018-01-21 07:07:18", updated_at: "2018-01-21 07:07:18", date: "2018-01-20 00:00:00", currency_id: 1>

Comment: Well, the spending looks good! What about  `User.first`,  `User.first.spendings` and `User.first.currencies`

Comment: #<User id: 1, firstname: "Cédric", password_digest: "$2a$10$M/copIRZbTsKa3b/Vh.A4OZhGmjv4u8vmjAG0afa2B2...", created_at: "2018-01-19 12:27:01", updated_at: "2018-01-19 12:27:01", remember_digest: nil> The next one, is like a lot ^^. And the third one as well, not a lot but still to much for the comment. Everything works fine in the console

Comment: Nevermind when I tried that : `@test = @current_user.currencies.first.spendings.sum(&:amount)` and use `@test` in the show it works... My bad

Answer (score 0):

I know there are other answers, but this is my approach.

Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = current_user
    @spendings = @user.spendings
    @currencies = @user.currencies
  end

end
```

Model

```
class Currency < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :spendings
  has_many :users, through: :spendings

  def user_spendings user
    spendings.where(user_id: user.id)
  end

  def total_user_spendings user
    user_spendings(user).sum(:amount)
  end

end
```

View

```
<h2>Spendings summary by currency</h2>
<table>
  <% @currencies.each do |currency| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= currency.symb %></td>
      <td><%= currency.name %></td>
      <td><%= '%.02f' % currency.total_user_spendings @user %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

<h2>Detailed spendings</h2>
<table>
  <% @spendings.each do |spending| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= spending.title %></td>
      <td><%= spending.description %></td>
      <td><%= '%.02f' % spending.amount %></td>
      <td><%= spending.currency.symb %></td>
      <td><%= spending.date.strftime('%d %B %Y') %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```