# Rails 5.1, chartkick a sum with multiple currencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, sum, ruby-on-rails-5, chartkick

I'm stuck on a tiny problem regarding chartkick. I have a rail app where you can create different currencies. You can then create a expense with a title, a amount and choose the currency from a list and the user_id. The relations are made and working. I have in my user controller something like this :

```
@user_spendings = @current_user.spendings.all.order('date DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)

@sums_by_currency = Currency.joins(:spendings).
  select(:symb, 'SUM(spendings.amount) AS amount').
  where(spendings: { id: @user_spendings.map(&:id) }).
  group(:symb)
```

And in my show view (as I want the expense from each user to be shown there) something like this :

```
    <% @sums_by_currency.each do |currency| %>
       <%= '%.02f' % "#{currency.amount}" %> <%= "#{currency.symb}" %>
    <% end %>
```

That shows me the sum for each spending depending on the currency.
I would like to use this total and use chartkick to display the spending, with the date when this spending has been created.
I've tried several things already
First I went with this just to see :

```
<% @sums_by_currency.each do |currency| %>

  <%= bar_chart currency.amount %>

<% end %>
```

Well I have to charts appearing but nothing shows up. Maybe the loop isn't the solution. Then I thought about the .map but I don't really know how to put that in place to be honnest.
I tried this aswell :

```
<%= line_chart  @current_user.spendings.group(:date).sum(:amount)  %>
```

That shows me the total spendings from all the currencies. I have to find out how to split all the currencies in different charts and show only the total amount from each currency.

If anyone can give me a clue I would appreciate it.

Thanks alot.

Comment: I found this Multiple series in the doc it looks like this : `<%= line_chart @goals.map { |goal|
    {name: goal.name, data: goal.feats.group_by_week(:created_at).count}
} %>` or this : `<%= line_chart Feat.group(:goal_id).group_by_week(:created_at).count %>`. With this I get several lines on the same chart. Could be the trick for my situation. I have to dig in that a little more. If anybody out here can confirm that it would be the thing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys I got it !
Took me 2 days only...
For the one interested in the answer here is what I did. I actually didn't change anything in the controller and I let the `@sums_by_currency` like it is.
Instead I went for that :

```
<%= column_chart @current_user.spendings.all.joins(:currency).group('currencies.symb').group_by_month(:date, format: "%B %Y").sum(:amount) %>
```

Give me all the spendings from the current_user from where I joined the currency that I grouped by symb. Then I grouped everything by month and I get the sum from the amount.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you need to pass a set of data to the chart, not lots of individual pieces of data for individual charts (ie what you've got with the loop). Using `map` to convert your currency-objects to their amounts makes sense eg

```
<%= bar_chart @sums_by_currency.map{|c| c.amount } %>
```

or if you need a name something like:

```
<%= bar_chart @sums_by_currency.map{|c| {name: c.unit, data: c.amount} } %>
```

Where `unit` is whatever currency unit eg `AUD`

Comment: Hey Taryn, I tried your code, it's almost working. I have a chart displayed with 2 currencies I created. But the amount doesn't appear and I guess it's because there is no date involved as a reference. So I tried soemthing like this : `<%= bar_chart @sums_by_currency.group_by_week(:date).map{|c| {name: c.symb, data: c.amount} } %>` but the chart doesn't load... Maybe because I didn't select the date into the @sums_by_currency in the controller. I will try some stuff here but there is a improvement, thanks ! If you have any other idea, please feel free :)

Comment: I tried like this as well : `<%= bar_chart @sums_by_currency.map{|c| {name: c.symb, data: c.amount.group_by_week(:created_at)} } %>` but no success as I have this on the refresh : `undefined method 'group_by_week' for 20:Fixnum`.... Hmmm don't really know

Comment: I'm just thinking about something, acutally this is not going to work. Because my `@sums_by_currency` is already calculating the total amount of the current_user in the controller with the SUM. And in my chart I'd like to have every single spending by currency and by month. So I guess it's good the get all the currencies but I have to work on a new variable I think to gather the rest of the infos.

Comment: I did this in my controller : `@sums_by_currency = Currency.joins(:spendings).
  select(:symb, '(spendings.amount) AS amount').
  where(spendings: { id: @user_spendings.map(&:id) }).
  group(:symb)`. I removed the SUM and I looped through just to test, I got the first amount in the first currency and the first amount in the second currency like so : `20.00 Chf.- 10.00 €.-`. But it doesnt show me all the spendings which is weird to me. And no date involved yet, I have to squizze that inside still...

Comment: I still didn't find. I did this : `@sums_by_currency2 = Currency.joins(:spendings).
      select(:symb, '(spendings.amount) AS amount').
      select(:symb, '(spendings.date) AS date').
      where(spendings: { id: @user_spendings.map(&:id) }).
      where(spendings: { date: @user_spendings.map(&:date) }).
      group(:symb)`. and that in the view : `<% @sums_by_currency2.group_by_month(:date).each do |currency| %>
<p><%= '%.02f' % "#{currency.amount}" %> <%= "#{currency.symb}" %><%= "#{currency.date}" %></p>
<% end %>`. I got all the spendings by currency and date, but no chart :(

Comment: Ok I got this working (almost). I have this now : `<%= column_chart @current_user.spendings.all.group(:currency_id).group_by_month(:date, format: "%B %Y").sum(:amount) %>`. Except that I still have to find out how to change the :currency_id into the symbol

Comment: hehe - Just got here and enjoying watching how you figured it out :) I'm not entirely sure of what you have in your currency model, but I'd reckon that
`currency_id` to the symbol can be done separately eg something like `Currency.find(currency_id).pluck(:currency_symbol)` assuming you have the currency-symbol as a column on the currency table.

Comment: You are right Taryn. I have Name and Symbol as column  on the currency table. Nice, I will try the .pluck, never used it and didn't know about it. I give a shot, thanks ;)